# jquery, replace one hyperlink link with another hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my html page have Two hyperlinks.

```
<a href="#" id="demo1" onclick="onClick_Demo1()" >Demo1</a>
<a href="#" id="demo2" onclick="onClick_Demo2()" >Demo2</a>
```

When we click `Demo1` hyper link.. `Demo1` hyper link replace with `Demo2` hyper link.

as well as When we click `Demo2` hyper link.. `Demo2` hyper link replace with `Demo1` hyper link .

I'm doing like this..

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $('#demo2').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
function onClick_Edit(){
  $('#demo1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
```

Suggest me..

Comment: Why don't you try show/hide when click......:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one..

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#demo2').hide();
    });
    function onClick_Edit() {
        $('#demo1').hide();
        $('#demo2').show();

    }
    function onClick_Edit() {
        $('#demo1').show();
        $('#demo2').hide();

    }
</script>
```